# How to determine the first element in a recursive foreach function?

Tags: php

I have a function generating nested navigation menu:

```
function recursive_foreach($array, $display) {
    $out = '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        ... 
        $out .= '<li class="'. $is_active . $is_parent . '"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $value['name'] . '</a>'; }   
        if (is_array($value['has_children'])) { 
            $out .= recursive_foreach( ...
        }
        $out .= "</li>";
    }   
    $out .= '</ul>';    
    return $out;    
}
```

I want to add css class just to the first "ul" element. I know how to determine first element inside foreach loop but how can I get it outside of it?

Comment: What is recursive about that?

Comment: I'm missing how this is recursive.

Comment: I didn't show here the whole function. In the place where I have 3 dots, Im calling: if(is_array($value['has_children'])) { $out .= recursive_foreach(....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best pass an appropriate parameter:

```
function recursive_foreach($array, $display, $first = true) {
    ...
    recursive_foreach($foo, $bar, false);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CSS selector `:first-child` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child)) or `:first-of-type` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)) to target the respective `<ul>` element, so you don't need to add a specific class to that element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) CSS Selector. :)

So, your CSS should look this way:

```
ul li:first-child { /* CSS Code */ }
```

It is compatible with:

- IE 7+
- Firefox
- Chrome
- Safari

Because you can use it to target it using Pure CSS and you don't need to change the markup! :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally the first `$key` is zero so you could check for that condition:

```
$first = $key === 0;
```

If your first key is different, use the first key:

```
$first = $key === $firstKey;
```

If your first key changes, obtain it first:

```
list($firstKey) = array_keys($array);
```

Hope this is helpful.

In CSS itself you can also just use the [`:first-child` pseudo-class<sup>*CSS2*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child). So no need to add a class [for various browsers<sup>*Browser Support*</sup>](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2).

Answer (score 1):

[:first-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) is nice, but isn't totally compatible.